# How to get data from jQuery ajax post with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Hi so I have a jquery post data that i'm sending:

```
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: app.config.backend_2 + '/notifications/usernames',
                    data: data,
                    contentType: 'application/javascript',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
```

and this is my express receiver:

```
 exports.save_usernames_for_notifications = function (req, res, next) {
    var start = function () {
       console.log(req);
    };

     start();

};
```

What do I do to get the data from the ajax to log it in the `save_username_for_notifications` function?

Comment: change your content type to application/json unless you want to use JSONP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a body parser middleware in your expressjs application to parse your JSON req object

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

To configure it, you need this code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // this is used for parsing the JSON object from POST
```

Then to get your data in your express application just do this

```
console.log(req.body.data)
```

Comment: Yep this worked. put it on the very top after requiring the body-parser. Thanks a ton :)